# Why do I get Uncaught type error in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using jQuery in my page. I imported the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cookie.jquery.js"></script>
```

Changed the name of the cookie plugin since my TomCat server blocks the original name. I am getting the following error in the console and my jQuery code doesn't work!!! Why am I seeing this??

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'cookie' AlertConfiguration.jsp:92
```

This is my jQuery:

```
 if($.cookie('remember_select') != null) {
       $('.XCONPVAL option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
       $('.limitemailalertvalue option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
       $('.siteID1 option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
       $('.groupID1 option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
       $('.divisionID1 option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    }

    $('.select_class').change(function() {

       $.cookie('remember_select', $('.XCONPVAL option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});
       $.cookie('remember_select', $('.limitemailalertvalue option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});
       $.cookie('remember_select', $('.siteID1 option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});
       $.cookie('remember_select', $('.groupID1 option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'}); 
       $.cookie('remember_select', $('.divisionID1 option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});

    });
```

[image: Hierarchy] This is my folder hierarchy. I have my js file in the js folder. My JSP  is in the jsps folder.

Comment: Are you sure the path to your cookie plugin is correct?

Comment: you js file `cookie.jquery.js` is not loaded properly, there might be some path issues.

Comment: @Felix see my edited post. I included my folder hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the issue:

in your `if`:

```
$('.groupID1 option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]')
      .attr('selected', 'selected');*/
      ///---------------------------^^----this
```

and in your change function:

```
$.cookie('remember_select', $('.groupID1 option:selected').val(), 
          { expires: 90, path: '/'}); */
       ///----------------------------^^---you have this at end of this line
```

Comment: That was a type mistake. Forgot to remove the comments while posting here

Answer (score 0):

The path for your file is incorrect, change from:

```
<script src="../js/cookie.jquery.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="js/cookie.jquery.js"></script>
```

since your `index.html` is the same directory as your `js` folder.

Comment: @AnushaHoney is it the correct file name `cookie.jquery.js` ?